# splitting string of value and sending to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I am trying to split a string of values actually individually and trying to send it into database via Store procedure but i can't figure out that how ?

String to be Split: "2013-03-31,1299,2013-03-31,1099,9888, 0"
CODE:

```
public bool SqlInsert(String parametersString)
{
       //It should be split here
       SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(conStr);
       SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand("AddCoordinates", sqlCon);
       sqlCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

       sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@AddedDateTime", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "";
       sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@IMEI", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "";
       sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@RecordedDateTime", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "";
       sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@Latitude", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "";
       sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@Longitude", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "";
       sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@IsParking ", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = true;

       try
       {
           sqlCon.Open();
           int NoRows = (int)sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();      
       }
       catch (Exception ex) { }
       finally
       {
           sqlCon.Close();
       }

       return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like it's just comma delimited, in which case try:

```
string[] parts = "2013-03-31,1299,2013-03-31,1099,9888, 0".Split(',');
```

However, that makes working with parts a bit awkward, so we can go a step further:

```
string[] fields = new string[] {"date","imei","recorded_date","lat","lon","is_parking"};
List<string,string> dict = Dictionary<string,string>();

for(var i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++) {
    var key = fields[i];
    var value = parts[i].Trim(); // You may or may not want to trim the value

   dict.Add(key,value);
}
```

You can then pull the individual fields you want and convert them to the type you need, for example:

```
int imei = int.Parse(dict["imei"]);
```

Of course, I'm sidestepping a couple of issues like type conversion failure and disparities between parts and fields, but you get the general idea.

Comment: thanks sir but it's too hard for a beginner to understand, please make it bit easy

Answer (score 0):

The approach mentioned by @Lloyd is the easiest one.Here is the code for your understanding.

```
        string[] parts = "2013-03-31,1299,2013-03-31,1099,9888, 0".Split(',');
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@AddedDateTime", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = parts[0].ToString();
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@IMEI", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = parts[1].ToString();
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@RecordedDateTime", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(parts[2].ToString());
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@Latitude", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = parts[3].ToString(); ;
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@Longitude", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = parts[4].ToString(); ;
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@IsParking ", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = ((parts[5].ToString().Trim()).Equals("0"))? true: false;
```

Hope it helps!